# Do I need to remove Apache2 before changing the PPA to latest version - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache-2.4, apt, ubuntu-14.04

Just finished installing Ubuntu 14.04.  I did a distribution install with LAMP stack.  I decided I want to run PHP7, MariaBD and latest Apache2.  I have got the PHP7 and MariaDB in place, now I want to change to the latest apache2 using the https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2 PPA.  Before switching this out, do I need to remove the current Apache2 using apt-get remove apache2(etc) ?  Or am I able to just add the new PPA and run the apt-get update/upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest starting over with a minimal OS install and adding to that from your choice of repositories.

While cleaning up is possible, you might as well test install from nothing.

Comment: This is the conclusion I had come to as well.  Nothing but problems with that deploy so far.